# Lin Algebra Simple Proof of identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing, factoring

I kind of have an idea how to do it but don't know how to follow through with proving:

Prove:

$|ab| \le \frac 12(a^2+b^2)$

This is what I have so far, not sure how to complete the proof:

Pf.

$2|ab| \le (a^2+b^2)$

$0\le a^2+b^2-2|ab| $

Then I think it has something to do with $a^2$ and $b^2$ are always positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using of your work we obtain:
$$a^2+b^2-2|ab|=|a|^2|+|b|^2-2|a||b|=(|a|-|b|)^2\geq0.$$
Done!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Not exactly, but the idea is to use squares, yes. If you play with $(a+b)^2 \geq 0$ you'll get $a^2 + b^2 \geq -2ab$, and so $(a^2+b^2)/2 \geq -ab$. If you start with $(a-b)^2 \geq 0$ instead you'll get $(a^2+b^2)/2 \geq ab$. Together, these two inequalities mean that $(a^2+b^2)/2 \geq |ab|$, as wanted. I'll let you fill the details, it is instructive.

Comment: So the point is to use both inequalities? I'm not sure how to show that, is there any more advice you can give me? I'm still kind of lost.

Comment: Given two numbers $x$ and $y$, saying that $x\geq |y|$ is the same as saying that $x\geq y$ **and** $x\geq -y$ simultaneously (try to understand why). We're checking this for $x =(a^2+b^2)/2$ and $y=ab$.

Comment: I get it now, Thank you!